# How to test master qualification in worker sandbox in Amazon MTURK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I am testing an application which is integrated with Amazon Mechanical Turk. In order to test it I need to accept HITs which require master qualification **(in mturk sandbox)**. How can I get Master Qualification as a **Sandbox Worker**?

I have requested for master qualification from dashboard so many times.Still  I cannot get it. Does anyone have any idea to proceed testing?

One solution I saw was to remove master qualification requirement from HIT and proceed testing, and that is not possible in my scenario. Thanks

Comment: Why is that not possible? The qualification should not change the behavior of the HIT itself, other than how it is displayed in the HIT list and accepted.

Comment: Agree with Thomas here. But to answer your question, you cannot request (or otherwise take actions) to become a Master on the Sandbox environment. Your only way to test your HITs with your Worker account will be to remove the Masters qualification.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Prob is HIts are created by a separate service which I have no permission to make any change in the existing HIT creation process. Anyway It is good to know that I cannot request master qualification in the sandbox environment.